# Broken github scrapy repo?

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, scrapy

I've tried debugging this repo (https://github.com/dsuess/arXiv-vs-viXra) and have had some progress but I'm not sure what the issue is. I'm on Windows 10 OS and scrapy.py only runs on Python 2.7 to my understanding on Windows. I keep getting this error, when I run the original repo:

````
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 145, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 267, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 145, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 347, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 73, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\kaybo\Downloads\arXiv-vs-viXra\crawlers\spiders\arxiv.py", line 21
    print(f'Crawling {category}')
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```
````

Comment: You are using python3 syntax with python2 also f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6. Try something like `print 'Crawling {}'.format(category)`

Comment: Thanks for the response Abdul. I did suspect something like this and tried running everything through the 2to3 python package. Do you think that would work or should I just modify the syntax manually?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Ran it all through the 3to2 python package and got 3 errors:
`RefactoringTool: Can't parse arXiv-vs-viXra\crawlers\spiders\arxiv.py: ParseError: bad input: type=3, value=u"'Crawling {category}'", context=('', (21, 11))
RefactoringTool: Can't parse arXiv-vs-viXra\crawlers\spiders\vixra.py: ParseError: bad input: type=3, value=u"'{self.baseurl}/{category}'", context=('', (22, 19))
RefactoringTool: Can't parse arXiv-vs-viXra\models\conv.py: ParseError: bad input: type=3, value=u"'loss: {training_loss}, acc: {training_accuracy}'", context=('', (185, 38))`